# Why aren't my images being displayed when using string interpolation for src links, in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working with Vue.js and having trouble getting a couple of images, from the local directory, rendered. What I find rather bizarre is this happens when using string interpolation as seen here:

```
<img :src="`../../assets/images/${category.imgUrl}.jpeg`" :alt="category.name">
```

...whereas the below code results in the expected output i.e. image is rendered.

```
<img class="app-link app-link--google" src="../../assets/images/googlestore.png" alt="Google play store link">
```

The resulting `src` string and, thus, relative link in the first snippet would be similar to the second one, wouldn't it? What is it that I'm missing?

Below is the complete code for the component in question.

```
<template>
    <div class="explore">
        <h2>Explore by category</h2>
        <div class="categories">
            <div class="category" v-for="category in categories" :key="category.name">
                <router-link :to="`find${category.path}`">
                    <img :src="`../../assets/images/${category.imgUrl}.jpeg`" :alt="category.name">
                    <p>{{category.name}}</p>
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { categories } from '@/helpers';

    export default {
        name: 'explore',
        data() {
            return {
                categories,
            }
        },  
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    $body-color: #0f1721;
    $text-color: #ffffff;
    $link-color: #00a2c7;
</style>
```

Comment: What's the value coming up in category.imgUrl? is this a full url? Log the entire `../../assets/images/${category.imgUrl}.jpeg` and see the result.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi That would be a string corresponding to the name of the saved image file e.g tech.jpeg (without the extension part, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a variable, you'll have to call `require()`.

Either use static:

```
<img src="../../assets/images/something.jpeg" :alt="category.name">
```

Or, as said, when dynamic, via `require()`:

```
<img :src="require(`../../assets/images/${category.imgUrl}.jpeg`)" :alt="category.name">
```

> Why the need to include `require()` for it to work?

I think you'll understand it better if you first have a look at the rendered value at `src`. You'll notice there's no path there. In the end, it becomes a `data:image` string.

What happens is, because it uses webpack, your application is not deployed as several files, but as just one big bundle (file). This means that all components you have will be mashed up into one big .js file. And this file will have to include the images as well. So they can be "inside a .js file", they "inline" the images as `data:image` strings.

When you declare the `src` statically, webpack knows the path to that image at "compile time" and it fetches and inlines it right away.

But webpack knows no `:src`, so it ignores it. Webpack does know, otoh, what `require()` is. Basically `require('somefile')` means "paste the whole content of `somefile` right here". And as you do `require('someimage.jpeg')` what it does it it pastes the contents of that image *as a `data:image` string*.

Comment: Thank you! Yours did the trick. If you don't mind me asking, why the need to include 'require' for it to work?

Comment: No, we don't mind at all. Ask away! My comment became too bit as typed it so I appended it to the answer. Please have a look!

Comment: Thanks again for the comprehensive explanation. Really appreciate it.